# Is it possible to use a BigRock domain with a Bluehost VPS hosting?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, wordpress, web-development, vps

I own a website which is hosted by BigRock. I also bought the domain from them. Now, I want to upgrade to a VPS hosting plan and I prefer Bluehost due to their cheap prices. Will it be possible to use the BigRock domain with the Bluehost hosting? The website runs on WordPress. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, it is quite a common practice.

You will either need to change the nameservers if you want bluehost to handle the DNS, or change the A record if you want the DNS as is but have the site at bluehost.

Comment: BigRock has a help document that shows how to edit DNS there.   The easiest way to use Bluehost VPS would probably be to create an A record at BigRock pointing to the IP address of the VPS: https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/633/0/editing-your-domains-dns-records

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this.  Here's the documentation on BigRock for this task:

https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/565/0/changing-your-domain-name-servers

Now, when you set up the host plan with Bluehost, they'll ask what your domain is, just give them the domain in question and you can even tell them that you're going to be pointing that domain to your account there.  You can get details for that when you set up your hosting.

Once the host plan is established, you can log into your Bluehost CPanel and get your DNS (Domain Name Server) server details, if you didn't get them from Bluehost already.  Once you have the information, then use the link above to help you re-point your domain to Bluehosts DNS servers.  Those DNS servers will determine, based on your domain, on which physical server your site is stored.

It can take up to 72 hours for domains to point to the new server, but in my experience, it takes minutes to a few hours.  Also, depending on how you intend have email setup, you'll need additional information and configuration, but both companies can help you with that.  You'll be looking at things like A records, CNAME records, and MX records.  These settings help identify and route email traffic vs regular internet traffic and so forth.  This is why you'll want to talk to both companies for your account particulars.

It may sound intimidating, but there are only a few settings and once you've configured them, it should be pretty much set it and forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is very common, most businesses will have their DNS managed by one company and have their services managed by another. This is known as a failover, if one company fails/loses interest in the business. You will not completely lose your setup. Blue host provides a KB Article here: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/559

This shows how to edit their DNS, this may be useful for BigRock.

Thank you.

Comment: "This is known as a failover, if one company fails/loses interest in the business. You will not completely lose your setup"  What??????